# how to eliminate duplicate values in jsp expression language?

Tags: jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${listOfRoutes}" var = "route">
                <option value="${route.source }" >${route.source }</option>
              </c:forEach>
```

here the listOfRoutes contains Route(id,source,destination) objects.
here i want to show only distinct sources.
how to do this, plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Set` to store source by iterating list because `Set` doesnot allow duplicate then use `Set` to populate source in the option, please have a look in below code.

```
<%
 Set setSource = new HashSet(); 
for(Route route:listOfRoutes){
 setSource.add(route.getSource()); 
 }
 %>


<c:forEach items="${setSource}" var = "source">
<option value="${source}" >${source}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

if you want options to have sorted values, then please use `TreeSet`.

Comment: you are welcome buddy..if this worked for you, you should mark this as accepted answer not the other one.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to decide what makes a route distinct from another one. Different ID? Different ID-Source-Destination?

Then, implement `equals` and `hashCode` on your `Route` object. The IDEs generally have an option to generate these methods by choosing which fields must be part of the computation.

And finally, use a `Set<Route>` to store the routes, instead of a `List<Route>`. You may choose `LinkedHashSet` as implementation if you want to preserve insertion order. A Set is a collection that doesn't store duplicates, so it satisfies your need.

The JSTL code will stay identical.